# Are symbols bound with libs for dynamic linking?

Tags: linux, linker, dynamic-linking

Assume `test.c` refers to a symbol `s` defined in a shared lib `lib-1.so`, and `test.c` also links `lib-2.so`.

My question is, after compilation, whether `s` is bound with `lib-1.so`. In other words, if the definition of `s` is then moved from `lib-1.so` to `lib-2.so`, without re-compilation, will the dynamic linker `ld.so` fail in symbol resolution? Can you give some reference explaining it?

I notice for some symbols defined in libc, they will become, e.g., `xyz@libc.6`; does it mean that `ld.so` only searches `libc` for `xyz`, ignoring `xyz` defined in other shared libs?